# Xamarin forms Oauth2 Wunderlist API

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, xamarin.forms, wunderlist

I'm trying to make an app (for school) using [Wunderlist](https://developer.wunderlist.com/documentation). However, I have no clue how to authenticate users for the API. So I want to make a Xamarin.forms project, and there a login screen will appear, in the screen users can enter their username and password to authenticate, or if that is not possible, when the app loads, they redirect to the login page of wunderlist to authenticate and then return authenticated to the app to be able to use the app. Or if that isn't possible, I want to hard-code an authentication in it.

The problem is, I have no idea how I should implement this, I have no clue how Oauth2 works and how to use it in Xamarin. Could someone please help me?

Comment: use the Xamarin.Auth nuget package. Google it and read the documentation

Comment: @samgak That's the package I was planning to use, I just have no idea how to use it and the documentation is really weird to understand to me, I'm new to Oauth2...

Comment: There's samples here: https://github.com/moljac/Xamarin.Auth.Samples.NugetReferences

Answer (score 0):

Rule of the thumb, don't create your own. This is what I used in one of our projects. A YouTube tutorial of a Microsoft MVP. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mg4qvVBXfrI

Hope this helps.